# Return the "long_name" for the item that has types "locality"

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient, subscribe, rxjs-observables

I'm trying to print out the `long_name` for the item that has `types === "locality"`. I'm using Angular and httpClient, which makes an observable. I'm lost in the complexity of rxjs and js.
Can anyone help?

Service:

```
getGoogleGeo2(postalCode: string) {
    return this.http
      .get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${postalCode}ES&key=${api}`)
      .pipe(map(<T>(item) => item.results[0].address_components));
  }
```

Component:

```
this.geoService.getGoogleGeo2(postalCode).subscribe((item) => console.log(item));
```

I'm getting this in my console.log:

```
[
  { long_name: "08820", short_name: "08820", types: ["postal_code"] },

  { long_name: "El Prat de Llobregat", short_name: "El Prat de Llobregat", types: ["locality", "political"] },
];
```

In my component I'll need to save the value `El Prat de Llobegrat`, to then be used in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track

The next step is `filter`ing

And you can do it either during the `pipe`line of `rxjs` or after the value is already emitted

I suspect you want it during the pipeline

Then either extend the current `map` in the `rxjs pipe` procedure, or append another `map` to the chain,
and add the filter there:

```
.pipe(
  map(<T>(item) => item.results[0].address_components.filter(value => value.types.includes('locality'))
);
```

or

```
.pipe(
  map(<T>(item) => item.results[0].address_components),
  // another item in the pipeline
  map(values => values.filter(value => value.types.includes('locality'))
)
```

Comment: I was wondering why use includes('locality') and not === "locality"?

Comment: `types === 'locality'` would be the correct way to check, if `types` held a primitive `string` as a value, as in: `{..., types: 'locality'}`. But the case here is that `types` holds an array of strings, and therefore the operation required is a search of the specific value _within_ the array. There are several methods to check for the existence of an item in an array, the most common are: `Array.findIndex()` - and check if the returned value is greater than -1, as in: `Array.findIndex(item => item === 'locality' ) > -1` , and the other one is `Array.includes` which is essentially the same

Answer (score 1):

Array find will return you the object that matches the required condition inside its callback. Foreg :-

```
this.geoService.getGoogleGeo2(postalCode).subscribe((item) => 
          console.log(item.find((value)=>value.types.includes("locality")).long_name)
);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it